# MySQL Count mutual friends between multiple users

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to count mutual friends between `A` user and a list of other users `(A, B, C, D, E...)`;

Here is an example of my current `relations` table:

```
INSERT INTO `relations` (`id`, `related_to`, `user_id`) VALUES
(1, 10, 1),
(2, 12, 1),

(3, 10, 2),

(4, 12, 3),
(5, 10, 3),

(6, 10, 4),

(7, 3, 5),
(8, 2, 1),
(9, 1, 3);
```

And now i would like to count mutual friends betwen user `1` and users `(2, 3, 4)`

So what i should get as result is user `2` would have one mutual friend, user `3` would have two mutual friends and user `4` would have one mutual friend.

Here is [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20833/2/0) for testing and select statement shows which fields should i get once correct query is written.

**EDIT** I think i should correct my self, i don't need to get rows of users that are related, I actually need to get a COUNT result for each user id, for example `[3] => 2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would this work?

```
SELECT r1.user_id AS first_user
, r2.user_id as second_user
, COUNT(r1.related_to) as mutual_friend_count
FROM relations r1
INNER JOIN relations r2
ON r1.related_to = r2.related_to AND r1.user_id <> r2.user_id
GROUP BY r1.user_id, r2.user_id
```

I joined the table onto itself using the related_to column, grouped by user pairs and counted the number of 'related_to's between them

Comment: Yes, ineed it does, just one more question, would this be slow with say 100k rows?

Comment: If both fields were indexed, it would be very fast.  If they weren't, I would still imagine it would be relatively quick, because they are both integer fields.  You probably won't know until you try it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT count(s.sum),s.user_id 
from (select count(id) as sum,user_id from relations
WHERE user_id != 1 and RELATED_TO in (select related_to from relations where user_id = 1)  group by RELATED_TO,user_id) as s group by user_id;
```